# Subtract time fields in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a table in Access 2013 which will follow the daily attendance at work. 
In a day, people need to work 8 hours. 
Here is a screenshot of the table: 
[image]

Column Total is = Time Until - Time From and that is ok.

Column Missing has this = 8-Format(24*Int([Total])+Hour([Total]);"0") & ":" & Format([Total];"nn")

The problem is in Missing column. 
If in Total column it says that a person did 7 hours, than in Missing column need to be 1 hours (1 hour missing to complete 8 hours daily work)

Notice the second and last rows ... for some reason it doesn't calculate correctly...

When there is 30 mins... it doesnt calculate right... in the last row, it should be 1:30 missing (to complete 8 h in a day)

How do I calculate it?

Comment: What are the datatypes of *Time From* and *Time Until*?

Comment: they are Date/Time datatype

Comment: Good.  Thanks.  What do those fields contain as the date component?  If you run this query, do you get *1899-12-30* in all cases?  `SELECT Format([Time From], "yyyy-m-d"), Format([Time Until], "yyyy-m-d") FROM YourTable;`

Comment: these are the results:1899-12-30.....  http://prntscr.com/7askka

Comment: Will *Time From* and *Time Until* always be from the same date, meaning they will never span midnight?

Comment: I think so, yes. Because, we will track only working hours during the daytime. Normal working hours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79152/discussion-between-volkan-and-hansup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date/Time values are actually double-precision float numbers.  That means you can do math directly on them.  In the results from a query, the computed values may be displayed as a double-precision float ... but you can then use `Format()` to present them in your desired time format.

I tested this query with your sample data in Access 2010.  It returns the results I think you want.

```sql
SELECT
    t.[Time From],
    t.[Time Until],
    Format((t.[Time Until] - t.[Time From]), 'h:nn') AS [Total],
    Format(#08:00# - (t.[Time Until] - t.[Time From]), 'h:nn') AS [Missing]
FROM tblVolkan AS t;
```

For any case where *[Total]* is greater than 8 hours, perhaps you may prefer to display *[Missing]* as a negative value.  If so, substitute this expression ...

```sql
IIf(#08:00# - (t.[Time Until] - t.[Time From]) < 0, '-', '')
    & Format(#08:00# - (t.[Time Until] - t.[Time From]), 'h:nn') AS [Missing]
```

Comment: Well, we will not have negative hours... thats ok. But I do have a question... how do I sum it up? It gives me error. I would like to have a sum of missing... is that possible? thanks

Comment: That could be tricky.  If the sum of *Missing* is 26.5 hours, how and where should that be presented?  I'm thinking you should do that with a different query.

Comment: well, we need a sum of missing hours in a month... is there a way to convert somehow and make it work? I just need it in one access form textbox... :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79168/discussion-between-volkan-and-hansup).